# reputation in Meta and Main sites out of sync?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I can see that my reputation in Apple stack exchange site and meta sites are out of sync right now. Is there a known problem or is this the expected behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small delay between when they update. Check back in a few minutes and it should be fine.

Comment: Child meta accounts are synced hourly.